# graphene возврашает null

Tags: python, django

разбираюсь с graphene, получаю в ответе null

models.py

```
class ChatMessage(models.Model):

chat_id = models.TextField(max_length=64, default='')
message = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
```

schema.py

```
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
import graphene
from chat.models import ChatMessage


class Mesages(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatMessage

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    messages = graphene.List(Mesages)

    def all(self, info):
        return ChatMessage.objects.all()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

запрос

```
{
  messages {
    message
  }
}
```

ответ

```
{
  "data": {
    "messages": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def all(self, info):
    return ChatMessage.objects.all()
```

заменить на

```
def resolve_messages(self, info):
    return ChatMessage.objects.all()
```

Название функции должно быть равна **resolve_{название_поля}**.

Подробнее: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/9da46e8c998c14ec603fef2060af41530af5d45c/docs/types/objecttypes.rst#resolvers